# Putting soft questions on hold unproductive?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I understand you want questions that can be answered definitively, that's the point of a stack. But given how many sappy personal advice questions you're getting, maybe it's time to create a support group to redirect them to, or maybe find an existing one, because just putting these questions on hold is a dick move.

Mathoverflow is more lenient, they even have big-list and soft-question tags for such questions, might be a good idea to have these as well, especially considering that it's a soft-ish stack already.

Edit: there can be no *confuson* here, and it is imperative that this issue is resolved. Make no mistake: human questions are the most important ones, not questions about finding printed C++ standard. There *must* be a high quality community where they can be answered, because turning away people who seek advice from seasoned programmers on a site called "Programmers" is downright criminal. I don't believe that a community where such questions are welcome can be divorced from a community with more hard questions, or its reputation system would go haywire. So it's either SO or this one.

Comment: [We already tried supporting these kinds of questions.  We even gave them their own site.  Sadly, it didn't work out.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Mathoverflow pulled it off, why can't we? Like I said, such questions cannot be divorced from the main community, they must be integrated into it.

Comment: MathOverflow has shown that they can do a good job of moderating and curating the questions. We have an abysmal track record on that. Furthermore, it *continues* to be very poor on the part of "if we leave these open, people post very poor answers". We don't go a day without some old answer getting a two sentence answer posted to it that's poor quality. New questions are even worse for the quality of the soft answers when left open. Math overflow has disciplined people answering, we don't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey they have two tags specifically for questions you so dislike, and it has worked out great for them.

Comment: @MichaelT, but putting such questions on hold without any directions is like a slap in the face of people seeking advice. At the very least we should give pointers in the on hold description.

Comment: If our Programmers community weren't so lazy at policing such questions, they might work here.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) exists on Stack Overflow for one reason only: the C++ community is ruthless at maintaining it.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko I assume you've looked at the [tour] and the [help/on-topic] and followed those links. Most people skip past them. For the custom close reasons, if you have suggestions on how to reword them, please suggest those. Much of it, however, just echoes the information provided in the help center and here on meta.

Comment: @MichaelT If those kinds of questions are the only ones allowed here, then what's the point of having this site in the first place? SO covers all of these! And where should I go with questions on software development history, for example? Or are they not legitimate questions?

Comment: We have a [tag:history] tag though it requires that a person ask it well. Asking a history question isn't an easy thing to do. Much of the design and architecture questions are off topic on Stack Overflow where it is assumed you've got code and errors to start with rather than something on a white board and a problem realizing the design.

Comment: @MichaelT software architecture is a viable topic, but if it's the main one on this site, it's better to rename it. the name "Programmers" connotes that it's a site about people, not code, and *no one* is going to read the manifesto before asking a question, and not one should have to IMO.

Comment: Read the linked question, @Alexei. Then, if you still have concerns, lay them out in a new question with less hyperbole. Many topics *can* be constructive, but it takes a skilled hand to prevent them from going off the rails; a significant portion of the expertise here is devoted to developing such skill and guiding askers away from the cliffs.

Comment: We have an [unfortunate history to the name](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7145/). However, that doesn't mean one should ignore the FAQ for a given community or ignore its norms. Especially when those are easily accessible and shown to new users when they register for the site. Similar expectations are on all Stack Exchange sites in one form or another (look at software recommendations, mathoverflow, code review for some examples - or the mcve on SO). Hopefully after not reading the provided material once, the user can find the help center and revisit what is on topic or not.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate that you added weight to the ongoing (but ultimately meaningless) argument that the name of the site actually matters.  Can you tell *anything at all* about the scope and rules of a site from names like "Seasoned Advice," "Ask Different," and "Arqade?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm familiar with all of them, so I can't really answer. But neither of them is in conflict with the scope of the corresponding site. I can ask about spices on "Seasoned Advice", I can ask about Macs on "Ask Different", and I can ask about arcade games on "Arqade", but asking about programmers on "Programmers" is off topic.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko on Cooking, is the question of "I've learned how to bake a cake.  What do I need to do to call myself a proper chef" one that would remain open (note the superficial similarity to the question you answered)? or would it have [gotten closed](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/55314/the-mark-of-a-true-chef)?  Why would one believe that this site any different?

Comment: @MichaelT: Is that guy seriously floating the premise that you can tell how good a chef is by putting him on a scale?

Comment: @MichaelT I do believe there is a room for a couple getting started type questions (assuming they are well-articulated), and the rest can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko the problem with [where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6366/40980) isn't the topicality, but rather that they are often way too broad to be answered. If we were try to have a few 'where to start' we would have difficulty with *everyone* has a different **opinion** about how to answer it, and *everyone* asking it is coming from a different place. There are far too many questions and answers in that domain for us to be able to reasonably handle them with quality answers... and we still have the problem of people aren't disciplined in answering them.

Comment: @MichaelT yes, I understand the point about the discipline. But I do think that letting some sufficiently narrow questions of that kind live is a-OK and they won't cause any major disaster.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko the [stats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/193412) disagree.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko when people ask sufficiently narrow questions, they become *very* particular to that one person. The other questions can't become duplicates of them as they are each about different circumstances and experience. The problem with them is they keep getting new answers (you are suggesting not closing them) and crowding out the other questions that are being asked from the front page. The major disaster is that other people don't ask questions then and we don't foster the community that answers the hard questions.

Comment: @MichaelT I understand now, thanks

Comment: Thank you for understanding. Its not something that often comes easily. The design of the site focuses on particular kinds of questions, and where to start isn't one of them. We really do like where to start questions and the helping people that entails - just that it doesn't work well on the main site. They *do* however, work reasonably in [chat], and we really do enjoy helping people there. We try to provide information about [how to get to chat](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7248/) and would happily answer what questions are asked there - just they don't work on the main site.

Comment: *"If our Programmers community weren't so lazy at policing such questions..."* As an early member of the community, I find this very insulting. The problem wasn't laziness, the problem was the site scope changed dramatically, and this change was not clearly explained to the community. When the majority of the community does not understand what the site owners want, then they are not going to moderate the site according to those standards. We built the site based on one scope, then it got changed to another. For a rough timeline, see [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/3412/1130)

Comment: And for the record, I'm in full agreement that the site name is very misleading and should be changed. [Change the name of Programmers to something that more accurately reflects the site scope?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/3718/1130), [Renaming the site to match its FAQ or changing the FAQ to match the site name?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2948/1130), and [On a name for the site and the questions asked](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7147/1130) to mention a few...

Comment: Eh, I don't think the lazy community remark had anything to do with the early phases of the site @Rachel. The community _today_ is lazy at policing soft questions, and it's been more than a couple of years that the scope has been clarified and solidified.

Answer (score 2):

Just because help vampires are common doesn't mean you should feed them.

Comment: That's demeaning. Novices seek guidance and advice from seasoned professionals all the time, and it is important that we provide them with good advice. Only a complete sociopath would compare that to vampirism.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko see http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Comment: How is making the Programmers stack about programmers and not programs enable said help vampires? Why is such behavior even relevant to the discussion?

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko did you  read the link GlenH7 posted?

Comment: @enderland people aimlessly asking for help with problems which are too big to solve are a strain on any community, and it is important to keep those in check. That said, I'd be careful about qualifying whole groups as the the problem (aka help vampires) because it's polarizing, and therefore tends to escalate quickly.