# Can the more clear description of the sites scope on the 'Sign Up' page be repeated in at least the 'Ask Question' page?

Tags: feature-request

Plenty of discussion on the issue of the site's scope, here's my suggestion in [this Q&A](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7935/4-years-later-dear-stack-exchange-can-we-change-our-site-name) as an official feature request.

Before a user joins programmers.se they are welcomed with what I feel is a fairly clear definition of the sites scope:

[image: loggedout]

It is a well known fact that when *most* people 'Sign Up' for things on the internet, they don't feel like reading the basics until they're *in*.

When they're *in*, they are presented with this tidy, but empty header:

[image: loggedin]

Would it be too much to add a reminder here?

Even more critically, when a user who hasn't read the blurb on the 'Sign Up' page, rushes to click the 'Ask Question' button. They are presented with this ridiculously broad definition of what a good question is:

[image: question]

Am I missing something, or do others share my view that if, to the right of my 'Ask Question' form is a message which asks, 'Is your question about software development?' then I can ask debugging questions, library recommendations, conceptual questions, database questions, and pretty much everything else which we as 'Software Developers' deal with on a day to day basis.

**Why can't the more clear description of the sites scope on the 'Sign Up' page be repeated in at least the 'Ask Question' page?**

IMO a name change is way overkill, especially when it'd be tough to find a name which won't make the problem better, or potentially make it worse.

Comment: Because we have no control over what appears on the Ask Question page. =( So this is essentially another request for SE intervention, which is probably a good thing, but since http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7935/4-years-later-dear-stack-exchange-can-we-change-our-site-name was *completely* ignored by SE, be prepared to see little more than vigorous agreement from us users who can't do anything and total silence from the people who can do something.

Comment: Very true, but worth the punt. Hopefully this will be deemed trivial enough to honour. Fingers crossed