# Priorizing of feature requests

Tags: discussion

Having read [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8176/please-add-mathjax) question about a reasonable feature request and seen that it was closed as a dupe of a question from 2013 (and 2011 by another user), I wonder what is the best way

- to leave a note to the SE team that I would also like to see such a feature added.
- to advertise certain feature requests after some years again to get some feedback if there are more users now which think the feature would be beneficial for the site

Just upvoting those old feature requests seems to have no impact, since chances are high noone just notice about the upvote to such an old question. Asking about the feature again seems to be the wrong way, too (will get closed as a dupe, see above). Adding a bounty, as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106860/what-is-meta-protocol-for-re-requesting-ignored-feature-requests), simply does not work on Programmer's meta.

So what can I do increase the chance a good suggestion which was probably just forgotten over the years won't vanish completely?

Comment: see [What is Meta protocol for re-requesting ignored feature requests?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106860/165773) and questions linked to it at at MSE

Comment: @gnat: just tried to place a bounty in the Mathjax question - but it seems I cannot place a bounty here on meta.

Comment: you can do bounty only on MSE. At per-site meta like here your options are narrower: edit, answer, discuss in chat, maybe non-duplicate question or something like was done in [(4 years later)...](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7935/31260)

Comment: Mathjax is very expensive (in terms of resource usage).  That's the only reason it's not implemented everywhere.  Well, that, and most sites really do not need it.  The only sites that should have it are those that demonstrate a regular, ongoing need for nice-looking math equations (Physics is such a site).

Comment: @gnat: convert your second comment into an answer and I will happily accept it.

Comment: @DocBrown [there you go](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/8183/31260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many thorough discussion on this matter, refer [What is Meta protocol for re-requesting ignored feature requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106860/165773) and questions linked to it at at MSE.

Keep in mind that bounties, being one of most popular ideas expressed in these discussions, apply only at MSE. At per site metas there is no way to set bounty.

Over here your options are narrower: edit, answer, discuss in chat, maybe ask non-duplicate question or do something like was done in famous [(4 years later)...](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7935/31260) request.