# It's official! Programmers is now Software Engineering Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, new-site-name

Awww yeah. WOoooooooOOOOoooOOOOOoooT! PARTY TIME. Check out that domain name and logo!

Thanks Stack Exchange :-)

[image: free as in beer]

<sub>If you see any problems anywhere, please leave an answer to this question so we can track them.</sub>

Comment: WOOT!!!  WOOT!!!

Comment: Sweet! I'm buying a round. Come get em: `[_]P [_]P [_]P [_]P [_]P`

Comment: Where is @Rachel?

Comment: Celebrating with beer! Or apple cider for any underage folks around here ;-)

Comment: Count me in!!!! (Had to add the fourth exclamation point for character count.)

Comment: First redirect to put a smile on my face. Thanks to everybody involved for making this possible.

Comment: As a predominately Stack Overflow user who was a bit tired of seeing Software Engineering get treated like a dumping ground, I can only applaud this change.  I'm so happy for this site! :D

Comment: at last! nice. good job everyone

Comment: Huzzah!!!...Huzzah!!!

Comment: Love the new name and scope. Still confused by the coffee logo - it sort of screams "off-topic chatter", which was what we were trying to get away from, no?

Comment: Very tiny minor point, but the comment upvote triangles are truncated at the top.  Is that deliberate?  (Also: w00t!)  :)

Comment: @SteveBennett steam coming from that coffee cup is intended to demonstrate how off-topic chatter questions _evaporate_ from site front page scared off by new site name

Comment: @Wildcard seems like the flag icons are too.

Comment: Wait, did you just create the awesome and party tags for this question? Was there never a reason to have those before?

Comment: As null said, the tags [awesome] and [party] do not seem to belong to *any* question, especially on meta. Also, w00t!

Comment: I wonder if even a single one of the users can be rightfully considered a software engineer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Do you think the term is too broad, vague or idealistic?  like software architect?

Answer (score 63):

We made it, y'all! We just pushed the changes and now, after 8 long months...

- The name for the site has changed to Software Engineering Stack Exchange.
- The logo for the site has been updated to the one shown in the top left of the page.
- The default domain for the site has changed to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.
- The site scope has been simplified.
- The topic string for the site changed to "software engineering".
- The audience string for the site has been changed to "professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle who care about creating, delivering, and maintaining software responsibly".

We've tried to catch everything but...you know how software goes, so if you see any spots where site copy no longer makes sense or we're otherwise using the old, incorrect name let us know, preferably in a separate meta question. *Oh, and one more thing*

### Congratulations!

The community took the initiative to identify a critical, long overdue change, brought it to us, and remained (*mostly*) patient while we hashed out the implications and details together in endlessly drawn out stakeholder discussions. Yet everyone remained dedicated and resolute throughout, and at long last, we've shipped.

Well played, everybody. :)

Comment: Testing magic links: `[programmers.se]` [programmers.se], `[softwareengineering.se]` [softwareengineering.se] and `[se.se]` [se.se]

Comment: @Ana This was an effort undertaken by many. But I'd like to take a moment to thank you personally for every effort you made.  Job well done.

Comment: what about people who liked the old name and logo?  :-(

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson [every change breaks someones workflow](http://xkcd.com/1172/). The motivation for the change is almost totally unrelated to whether anybody *liked* the old logo and name. The point is that it attracted too many of topic questions and communicated the scope poorly. There were in fact additional changes applied (see Ana's answer) in an attempt to fix those problems overall.

Comment: Thank you Ana for your support and patience with us.  It is much appreciated!

Comment: excellent XKCD reference, @null.  thanks

Comment: @null In a similar vein: http://cube-drone.com/comics/c/ingeniuty-of-sorts :)

Comment: @null Great points. I liked the old name as well, but I definitely think software engineering is a bigger deterrant to off-topic questions and less likely to be mixed up with StackOverflow.

Though we're all still programmers :P

Comment: I personally like the new name SESE, now should it be pronounced 'seh seh' or 'cee cee'?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson they've been willingfully ignored "because they weren't following meta". In meta, those who had enough spare time on their hands to mess with other people's contents, blabbed forever about how bad they where at drawing logos, and then produced one.

Comment: @gbjbaanb It should be pronounced 'seize'.

Comment: are workplace related software engineering questions still allowed on this Q&A site or should they be redirected elsewhere?

Comment: @omouse Questions about the workplace or careers have not been allowed here for a very long time. The earliest confirmation of this I found was [a Meta post from 2010](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster).

Answer (score 22):

Quite pleased to see the change but I would still insist to get a more serious font for the title **SOFTWARE ENGINEERING** like they have on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), and [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

**The current font of the title still gives a comical(non-serious) feel**, IMO.

I also feel that it will look more professional to have the title like:
**`Software Engineering`** rather than all caps.

Comment: Fair, but have you *seen* most software engineers' handwriting? :)

Comment: @AdamLear I think the reason for all this fuss about title change of the site was that the newcomers used to post offtopic questions regarding programming. If the font is more serious one, it will send a message to the newcomers, IMO.

Comment: I take it *very* seriously, and happen to like it! ;-) Do you really think it seems childish? I think of it as pragmatic.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from, @AquariusTheGirl, but I don't think the logo is the problem. :) The people who post blatantly off-topic stuff aren't motivated by the "fun" logo. It's a far more complex issue than that. (FWIW, we get programming questions on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) every day/other day. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯)

Comment: Agree that the font doesn't make the site look trustworthy.

Comment: The original site layout and logo were made to convey a hand-drawn, marker-on-whiteboard feel ([as described and seen here](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/655/site-design-round-2)). Since the site logo doesn't have a hand-drawn appearance anymore, and is instead very polished graphics, the hand-writing-y logo text isn't really congruent. It's a holdover from an old design's ethos, in a new design that wasn't built with that ethos. Better to pick a font that matches the design ethos of the current header logo, IMO.

Comment: Have you seen software engineers do some graphic design? "PM wants another logo? <Opens MS Paint> Done!!" Ok seriously, we do need a better design here.

Answer (score 8):

Mobile app broke with the change.  The menu Item became 'Unknown Site Programmers' and clicking it crashed the app. Already filed a crash report through google.

Answer (score 1):

> If you see any problems anywhere, please leave an answer to this question so we can track them.

The comment "upvote" arrow icons and also the comment flag icons are truncated at the top.

(Also: Yay, new site name and scope!)

Answer (score -7):

Great. But where do we (and by "we" I mean the vast majority who follows and uses "programmers" and doesn't usually go meta) vote to express our disappointment with:

1. the whole renaming ordeal, (*If it ain't broke, don't fix it*)
2. the logo? (that font is *pure pain*, but the drawing is awful too: **the pedestals, the keyboard, the mouse, they're all wrong**. How about getting someone who can *actually* draw to do it?)

   > (Personally I think the only thing worth saving, there, is the geometric smoke out of the coffee cup, but that too, could use some more work)

Comment: If you missed the overwhelmingly discussed meta discussions ([15 questions tagged with new site change](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-site-name)) over the past _eight months_ and didn't make your objections known at that point or really heavily engage in that process, I guess personally I have minimal sympathy. That being said if you look at any of those questions nearly none of the "Software Engineering as a name" posts had any level of significant downvoting. [This](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8061/52929) is +154 / -4...

Comment: Well, it looks like you actually missed it. The logo has been discussed [here](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8254/177827) and it was said that to prevent further delay, no big changes can be made. There was also a question about the logo asked here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/78796 There's nothing stopping you from opening a question here on meta to ask for changes. Meta is the place to express your disappointment.

Comment: FWIW request for "whole renaming ordeal" has 6.7K views and 397 votes (+389/-8): [(4 years later) Dear Stack Exchange: can we change our site name?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7935/31260) On one hand it's only about half of [2013 mod election participation](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/5753/31260) but on the other hand for a request that was not supported by a system nor by SE management (as opposed to mod elections) participation looks fairly solid to me, as well as community support for the change

Comment: The entire community doesn't have to be involved in this process.  Only the people who care enough to engage need be.

Comment: I felt the exact same way when they changed the scope of the site in it's early NPR days! I just assumed Meta wasn't something I should care about since I figured it was run by "higher-ups" and doubted anyone would care what I said to say, but I was wrong. These sites are meant to be run by the Community, and the meta site is where anything related to the site gets discussed by the community. Including changes to site scope or name. Every opinion matters and usually gets considered, although not all ideas pass. I'd highly recommend paying more attention to meta if you participate in SE sites.

Comment: @Rachel: Nice to see you again.  Since the name change, question quality has shown signs of improvement.  Overall, I think the site is easier to understand for everyone.  The heavy-handed moderation you refer to in your profile has been noticeably absent; the questions that now get closed are the ones that even you would agree really need to be closed.  I personally feel like I'm now spending more time answering questions than I am moderating the site, which is what I really wanted all along.

Comment: Well these are just opinions. I both like the name and the logo.

Comment: I like the logo, it seems Mario Bros-inspired

Answer (score -9):

Sorry, landed here from an announcement on programmers. First time I encounter this site.

How is it different from all other programming-related sites? SO, Programmers, CS, Code Review etc?

Looking at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, I see questions like "Can a function be pure if it depends on an immutable class-level field?" (programmers), "How to use git when project files are on different drives?" (SO, U&L), "ASP.net Application - wait for sproc response from service broker" (SO), "Cyclomatic complexity vs performance" (CS).

Comment: This **is** programmers - it's been renamed.  [Here's some context as to why](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7935/220461).

Comment: This is a good example of that even with the renaming, the problems won't go away completely. Confusing always reigns. Hopefully softwareengineering can do a bit better than programmers.